# Two-column image grid

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position two images that span 100% across on each row, however, because each image has some padding and a border, it appears that 50% for each is too much. I also have another class for images that span 100%, but they seem to span further than the two smaller ones. Basically, I'd like to style both images to align with the wider image: http://jsfiddle.net/p80hrj4s/.

```
<div class="post-content"><a href="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rr2z22v0QgY/VDKGa9ovtnI/AAAAAAAAWbY/CXRKfU6WPcU/s1024/01-kp.jpg"><img class="left-half" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rr2z22v0QgY/VDKGa9ovtnI/AAAAAAAAWbY/CXRKfU6WPcU/s1024/01-kp.jpg"></a><a href="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rr2z22v0QgY/VDKGa9ovtnI/AAAAAAAAWbY/CXRKfU6WPcU/s1024/01-kp.jpg"><img class="right-half" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rr2z22v0QgY/VDKGa9ovtnI/AAAAAAAAWbY/CXRKfU6WPcU/s1024/01-kp.jpg"></a>

<div class="fullwidth"><a href="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rr2z22v0QgY/VDKGa9ovtnI/AAAAAAAAWbY/CXRKfU6WPcU/s1024/01-kp.jpg"><img class="fullwidth" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rr2z22v0QgY/VDKGa9ovtnI/AAAAAAAAWbY/CXRKfU6WPcU/s1024/01-kp.jpg"></a></div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to do this since what I've tried doesn't look right.

EDIT: Part of the issue is that the `right-half` image isn't full floated to the right -- I only seem to be able to push it all the way with `margin-right: -7px;`. I'm also testing it here: http://www.mtscollective.com/2014/03/gallery-wonder-years-real-friends-and.html#.VDKTeCmSz-0

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/p80hrj4s/3/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use box-sizing: border-box, and then you can add padding and border to the elements and it will calculate them inside that element, so it will not add the padding and border to the width :)

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box
}
```

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/p80hrj4s/1/

Comment: For box-sizing, `-ms-` prefix has never existed, `-webkit-` isn't needed since chrome 9 and safari 5. `-moz-` isn't either since FF 28. you might consider not using them. (more info here : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)

Comment: Thanks, Bojan -- that's very useful! For some reason, the right image is still not fully floated to the right. If I decrease its margin, it just becomes bigger than the left image, so I'm not sure how to fix that: http://www.mtscollective.com/2014/03/gallery-wonder-years-real-friends-and.html

Comment: The `post-content` section seems to have a width of 624px instead of 638px. I have no idea where that's set :/

Comment: You need to add .fullwidth {
/* margin-right: -6px; */
box-sizing: border-box;
} Remove margin-right, also post-content is actually 624px wide because it's parent is 638px wide but has padding . This is the parent .post-body{padding: 0 10px 12px 4px;}